# Best practice for storing DropDownList values in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, store

There are several approaches for storing the values for static DropDownLists in ASP .NET MVC:

1. Storing values in code
2. Storing values in a config file and loading them when the Application is started
3. Storing values in a database and loading the needed values on each request (and caching them)

Until now I preferred #3, because adding new values to a specific DropDownList means just adding a new entry in a database-table without having the application-server need to be restarted.

However, adding new values barely happens and loading values on each request slows down the performance. This is why I am planning to change my approach and want to ask you:

How do you handle this? Do you know an even better approach than the 3 mentioned above?

Comment: How about sticking with #3 (or any of the others for that matter), but adding some form of cache, so they don't need to be retrieved from the DB so often?

Comment: I am already using cache, but somehow disliked the idea that new added values are first seen when the cache timesout. But i guess thats not a big problem so I'll stick with it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*For static Drop down List, I will prefer to add values in controller and pass it in 
ViewData Like this  example in controller:::::*

`enter code here`var list = new SelectList(new []
                                   {
                                      new {ID="1",Name="name1"},
                                    new{ID="2",Name="name2"},
                                              new{ID="3",Name="name3"},
                                          },
                           "ID","Name",1);
           ViewData["list"]=list;

return View();  
In View

Comment: In view Do this:::<%=Html.DropDownList("list",ViewData["list"] as SelectList) %>